# Laravel model referencing wrong table in query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I am sure this is because of the eloquent, but the query is using the wrong table in `SELECT`.

here my model:

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{
    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
}
```

and here is my Controller:

```
class SubcategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

        $subcategories = Subcategory::all();

        return view('pages.subcategories', compact('subcategories'));

    }
}
```

and finally here my error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'developmnet.site.subcategories' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `subcategories` where `category_slug` = budgets limit 1)
```

as you can see from the error the table referenced in the query is `subcategories` when it should be `categories` table.

My question is how to reference the correct table in this model as I already have one for my main categories and it is working just fine.

Comment: Why do you believe it should be `categories`? Your class name is `Subcategory` so the table name will be `subcategories` if you don't overwrite it.

Comment: the reason is that I do not actually have a table with name of  `subcategories` in my `DB`. So if I was to overwrite this how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To overwrite the table name of a model you can define the `protected $table` property. In Your case:

```
class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    // ..
}
```

If you don't do that, Laravel will derive the table name from the class name. In your case: `Subcategory => subcategories`.

Comment: This is perfect now, thanks for your help and thanks for your explanation, now I have a bit more clue about how this works